# Missing hvc0 in Ubuntu Lucid Xen DomU

Tags: xen, console

I've just installed an Ubuntu Lucid 64bit image (from [Stacklet](http://stacklet.com)) as a Xen DomU, running under Xen 3.2.1 on Centos 5.2 64bit.
Everything is working fine, except my logs are flooded with:

```
/dev/hvc0: No such file or directory
```

I tried creating the device with `mknod /dev/hvc0 c 229 0` but the message just changes to:

```
/dev/hvc0: cannot open as standard input: No such device or address
```

Any hint on what I could try? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked at Stacklet and they told me that

> The Xen kernel used with 10.04 does
>   not require /dev/hvc0.  I recommend
>   the following:
>
> 1. remove /etc/init/hvc0.conf (or move it someplace else)
> 2. /boot/grub/menu.lst should reference tty1 instead of hvc0